# SQL Server - How to create table from openrowset with headers only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table **using a openrowset selection**. The idea is to only create the headers without content. So my idea was to use `SELECT TOP 0 FROM some_file.txt` as follows:

```
  select *
    into table_name
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Text; HDR=YES; Database=C:\folder_name', 
        'SELECT TOP 0 * FROM some_file.txt')
```

Unfortunately I have the follwing error triggered:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.".
```

If I put `SELECT TOP 1 FROM some_file.txt` it is working but I have as expected the first row added. Important: Do not propose `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` as a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ......

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO table_name
FROM ( 
    select TOP 1 *
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Text; HDR=YES; Database=C:\folder_name', 
        'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM some_file.txt')
      )A
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique is to add `where 0 = 1` to the query,

`select *
    into table_name
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Text; HDR=YES; Database=C:\folder_name', 
        'SELECT * FROM some_file.txt WHERE 0 = 1')`

or, more generally,

`select *
    into table_name
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Text; HDR=YES; Database=C:\folder_name', 
        'SELECT * FROM some_file.txt') as A
    WHERE 0 = 1`

but I suspect the latter query will execute the whole OPENROWSET before applying the WHERE clause.

The idea here is that SELECT...INTO is atomic and must create the target table if syntactically correct.  Because no rows meet the WHERE criteria, none are inserted into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not sure this will workout or not

```
select *
    into table_name
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Text; HDR=YES; Database=C:\folder_name', 
        'SELECT * FROM some_file.txt')
where 1=0
```